# How to remove all commit history from PR overview

Tags: git, bitbucket

In my pull request for each commit, I did `git commit --amend`.

But in the overview, I'm getting all the list of amended commits.

Like this, `UPDATED the pull request by adding 1 commit and removing 1 commitA moment ago`

This is getting added for each `amend` commit I make.

How to get rid of it ?

Comment: You don't. That's what bitbucket does when you (force) push amended commits.

Comment: I don't understand why you are even using `git commit --amend` here.  Amend is designed to rewrite the latest commit on a given branch.

Comment: If you're pushing the amended commits - i.e. rewriting history on the server - the server is able to pick this up; this is actually used in some workflows (I wanna say Gerrit's) to track modifications to a changeset while keeping the changeset internally "clean."

Comment: Its like for each review comments, I make changes and push to remove. Keeping the PR as single commit

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Abusing history rewriting on private in-progress branches is actually used in certain Git workflows, of the "make a single change perfect before merging" flavour. (Personally I think it's daft compared to using a normal branch and say squash merging it to reintegrate but what can you do...)

Comment: @millimoose Yes, I know why amend is used :-)

Comment: Then I suppose I don't understand why you're asking OP why he's using it here if you know the purpose?